# Redirect http symlink to https

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Imagine I got "www.example.com". Files in /var/www. I have a symlink, mail -> /usr/share/squirrelmail.
Now I would like to redirect www.example.com/mail to https://www.example.com/mail using htaccess. I have tried so many things. Everytime I get internal server error. Please help me. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mail$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I placed this in /var/www... Still gives me internal server error.

Comment: Did you enable mod_rewrite ? Also, do you have other rules in your htaccess ? By `/var/www` you mean your document root folder ?

Comment: I just installed this server and forgot to enable mod_rewrite. Just did. It works. Thanks. OMG. I feel so stupid.

Comment: This happens sometimes, don't feel stupid. If my answer was helpful, don't forget to accept it